# Running Airflow locally with Docker - error after docker-compose up

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

I am trying to run airflow locally with docker. But I got an error message after executing `docker-compose up` :

```
ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.26 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
```

The docker-compose version is v2.10.2, and I'm using an m1 chip.

Here's the full traceback of docker-compose up

```
> docker-compose up 
[+] Running 7/0
 ⠿ Container airflow-dags-redis-1              Running                                                                                                                          0.0s
 ⠿ Container airflow-dags-postgres-1           Running                                                                                                                          0.0s
 ⠿ Container airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       Created                                                                                                                          0.0s
 ⠿ Container airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1     Running                                                                                                                          0.0s
 ⠿ Container airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  Running                                                                                                                          0.0s
 ⠿ Container airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1  Running                                                                                                                          0.0s
 ⠿ Container airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  Running                                                                                                                          0.0s
Attaching to airflow-dags-airflow-init-1, airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1, airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1, airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1, airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1, airflow-dags-postgres-1, airflow-dags-redis-1
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | The container is run as root user. For security, consider using a regular user account.
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1     | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1     |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1  | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1  |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | 
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | DB: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:***@postgres/airflow
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | Performing upgrade with database postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:***@postgres/airflow
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | [2022-11-23 07:47:45,036] {db.py:1462} INFO - Creating tables
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1  | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1  |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:47:52 +0000] [83] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | Upgrades done
airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1     | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1     |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:48:20,076] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1  | BACKEND=redis
airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1  | DB_HOST=redis
airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1  | DB_PORT=6379
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:48:25 +0000] [83] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (83)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:48:25 +0000] [83] [INFO] Using worker: sync
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:48:25 +0000] [125] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 125
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:48:25 +0000] [127] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 127
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:48:25 +0000] [129] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 129
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:48:25 +0000] [131] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 131
airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1  | 
airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1     | BACKEND=redis
airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1     | DB_HOST=redis
airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1     | DB_PORT=6379
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | [2022-11-23 07:49:15,765] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | [2022-11-23 07:49:21,885] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  |   ____________       _____________
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  |  ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | ____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | ___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  |  _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:49:26,287] {triggerer_job.py:100} INFO - Starting the triggerer
airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1     | 
airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1  | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-scheduler-1  |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | airflow already exist in the db
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:49:49,628] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.28 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1       | 2.3.3
airflow-dags-airflow-init-1 exited with code 0
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:04,847] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:06,945] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:08,388] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:08,893] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:10,370] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:12,999] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:13,291] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:15,743] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:20,086] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.35 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:25 +0000] [83] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:125)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:26 +0000] [83] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:127)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:26 +0000] [83] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:129)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:26 +0000] [83] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:131)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:26 +0000] [125] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 125)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:26 +0000] [127] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 127)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:26 +0000] [131] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 131)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:27 +0000] [83] [WARNING] Worker with pid 131 was terminated due to signal 9
airflow-dags-postgres-1           | 2022-11-23 07:50:27.412 UTC [231] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:27 +0000] [83] [WARNING] Worker with pid 129 was terminated due to signal 9
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:27 +0000] [83] [WARNING] Worker with pid 127 was terminated due to signal 9
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:27 +0000] [180] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 180
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:27 +0000] [182] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 182
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:27 +0000] [83] [WARNING] Worker with pid 125 was terminated due to signal 9
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:27 +0000] [184] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 184
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:27 +0000] [186] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 186
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:50:42,521] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.26 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1     | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:356: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow-dags-airflow-worker-1     |   warnings.warn(
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:51:14,861] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.20 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:51:23,311] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.35 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:51:24,691] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.38 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:51:25,637] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.36 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:51:31,709] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.40 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:51:41,635] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.24 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:51:57,670] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:51:58,599] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:51:59,615] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:01,891] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:01,955] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:03,564] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:04,475] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:06,434] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:26,095] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.20 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:28 +0000] [83] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:180)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:28 +0000] [83] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:182)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:28 +0000] [83] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:184)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:28 +0000] [83] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:186)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:28 +0000] [182] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 182)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:28 +0000] [184] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 184)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:28 +0000] [180] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 180)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:28 +0000] [186] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 186)
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:30 +0000] [83] [WARNING] Worker with pid 184 was terminated due to signal 9
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:30 +0000] [83] [WARNING] Worker with pid 180 was terminated due to signal 9
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:30 +0000] [83] [WARNING] Worker with pid 186 was terminated due to signal 9
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:30 +0000] [236] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 236
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:30 +0000] [238] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 238
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:30 +0000] [83] [WARNING] Worker with pid 182 was terminated due to signal 9
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:30 +0000] [240] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 240
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:52:30 +0000] [242] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 242
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:53:38,534] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.27 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:53:43,427] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.21 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:53:50,683] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.21 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:53:53,144] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.20 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:54:13,423] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:54:14,241] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:54:14,871] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.21 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:54:16,329] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:54:18,351] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:54:19,050] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:54:19,515] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:54:21,955] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-webserver-1  | [2022-11-23 07:54:23,718] {providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow-dags-airflow-triggerer-1  | [2022-11-23 07:54:26,018] {triggerer_job.py:343} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.21 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines.
```

I allocated more resources to docker to fix this (CPUs: 4, Memory: 10GB, Swap: 2GB) but it didn't work.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a Mac with an Intel chip and I've also allocated every possible combination of resource to Docker, and I still have this same problem. It appears allocation of resources is likely not the solution.